# why does *& token return an error when trying to allocate memory inside a function

Tags: c, compiler-errors, pass-by-reference, dynamic-memory-allocation, function-declaration

I'm getting the following error when trying to allocate memory for any type of structure inside a function

```
expected ';', ',' or ')' before '&' token|
```

Here's a small code example that gets the error

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int carga( int *&x){

    x= (int*) malloc ( sizeof (int) *10);
    for(int i=0; i<10;i++)
        scanf("%d ",&x[i]);
}
int main()
{
    int *b;
    carga(b);
    free(b);
}
```

Also I would like an explanation of what does the *& token do if possible.

Comment: You seem to be trying to use a C++ reference argument (the `&` token) in a C program. C doesn't have such a reference argument type.

Comment: "what does the *& token do if possible."  It generates a compiler error and that's all it is good for.

Comment: Also, `malloc.h` was deprecated in the early Cretaceous era.

Comment: @achiente, could you please remove the 'c' tag for this question, and add a 'c++' tag? As others have pointed out, you're using a C++ operator here that isn't available (for that purpose) in C.

Answer (score 0):

In the function declaration

```
int carga( int *&x){
```

the tokens `*&` are not type specifiers. They form an expression that you may not use in a declaration.

Pay attention to that this statement

```
free(b);
```

will invoke undefined behavior because the pointer b was not initialized by an address of dynamically allocated memory.

It seems you mean something like the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

void carga( int **x )
{
    *x = (int*) malloc( sizeof (int) * 10 );
    
    if ( *x != NULL )
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
            scanf("%d", *x + i );
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    int *b;
    carga( &b );
    free( b );
}
```

Opposite to C in C++ you may write the function declaration like

```
void carga( int *&x );
```

In C++ the function can be defined the following way

```
void carga( int * &x )
{
    x = new int[10];
    
    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
            std::cin >> x[i];
}
```

and called like

```
int *b;
carga( b );
```

Comment: Now i'm probably screwed because that's the college textbook example of how to dinamically allocate memory inside a function. I'm 100 percent supposed to allocate memory inside a function and not in the main, what would be the correct way to do it?

Comment: @ashiente See my appended answer.

Comment: Your example uses linked lists, and i'm not supposed to used linked lists yet. In the test I simply allocated memory in the main and then passed the pointer as a parameter and it worked but it was marked as incorrect since I have to create the dynamic array inside the function

Comment: @ashiente There is neither linked list. You need to read a book on C and algorithms in C  for beginners.

Comment: @ashiente In the program I showed there is created a dynamically allocated array in the function as you have written.